# mongodb date range query optimization

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization

I need to find items which are in a date range or overlap it.

[image]

First i tried a simple $nor query

```
db.collection.find({
    $nor: [{
        "start.date": { $lt: start },
        "end.date": { $lt: start }
    }, {
        "start.date": { $gte: end },
        "end.date": { $gte: end }
    }]
});
```

and set a index on both date fields

> db.collection.ensureIndex({"start.date": 1, "end.date": 1});

but it will not use the index on query

```
"cursor": "BasicCursor",
"isMultiKey": false,
"n": 2,
"nscannedObjects": 100000,
"nscanned": 100000,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans": 100000,
"nscannedAllPlans": 100000,
"scanAndOrder": false,
"indexOnly": false,
"nYields": 781,
"nChunkSkips": 0,
"millis": 151,
"allPlans": [
  {
    "cursor": "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey": false,
    "n": 2,
    "nscannedObjects": 100000,
    "nscanned": 100000,
    "scanAndOrder": false,
    "indexOnly": false,
    "nChunkSkips": 0
  }
],
"type": "COLLSCAN",
```

another way i've tried is to use $or with the same index

```
db.collection.find({
    $or: [{
        "start.date": start,
        "end.date": end
    }, {
        "start.date": { $lt: start },
        "end.date": { $lt: end, $gt: start },
    }, {
        "start.date": { $gt: start, $lt: end },
        "end.date": { $gt: end }
    }, {
        "start.date": { $gt: start },
        "end.date": { $lt: end }
    }, {
        "start.date": { $lt: start },
        "end.date": { $gt: end }
    }]
});
```

It will use the index on query but $nor is even faster.

Is there a way to optimize the query or is it possible to use indexes on a $nor (it makes sense anyway ?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You search items that start anywhere before `end` and end anywhere after `start` (which is similar to how you express it with your `nor`, only slightly simpler):

```
db.collection.find({
    "start.date": { $lt: end },
    "end.date": { $gt: start }
});
```